# Filtering state logic for table react for multiple select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting a filtering strategy. I would like to filter my table based on a selected value. By default the all values should be selected based on an 'all' option in the select. I tried to implement a filtering logic and I am sure I am not doing it the right way, because the filtering does not work in some cases.
What is the correct way to apply the filtering here. Thanks. Below is a sample of what I attempted:

```
const App = () => {
    const [moduleSelected, setModuleSelected] = useState({value:'all'});
    const [variableSelected, setVariableSelected] = useState({value:'all'});
    const [valueSelected, setValueSelected] = useState({value:'all'});
    const [periodSelected, setPeriodSelected] = useState({value:'all'});
        const variables = [
        {id:"all", variable:"all"},{id:"subdomain", variable:"subdomain"}, {id:"category", 
         variable:"category"}];
    const valid = [
        {id:"all", variable:"all"},{id:"true", variable:"true"}, {id:"false", variable:"false"}];
...
const handleModuleChange = e => {
        console.log('module', e.target.value)
        setModuleSelected({value : e.target.value})
    }

    const handleVariableChange = e => {
        console.log('variable', e.target.value)
        setVariableSelected({value : e.target.value})
    }

    const handlePeriodChange = e => {
        console.log('period', e.target.value)
        setPeriodSelected({value : e.target.value})
    }

    const handleValueChange = e => {
        let boolvalue = Boolean
        e.target.value == 'true'? boolvalue = true:
        e.target.value == 'false'? boolvalue = false:
        boolvalue=null
        console.log('value', boolvalue, typeof boolvalue)
        setValueSelected({value : boolvalue})
    }

    let filteredComparables = [];
    moduleSelected.value === 'all' || variableSelected.value === 'all'||
    valueSelected.value ==='all' || periodSelected.value === 'all'?
        filteredComparables = new_comparables
        :filteredComparables = new_comparables.filter(comparable => (
            comparable.module == moduleSelected.value !== 'all'
            &&comparable.table == variableSelected.value !== 'all'
            &&comparable.is_valid == valueSelected.value !== 'all'
            &&comparable.period == periodSelected.value !== 'all'))
...

 return (
           <div>
              <select onChange={e => handleModuleChange(e)}>
                 {modules_data.map((obj) => {
                        return(
                            <option value={obj.variable}>{obj.variable}</option>
                         )
                  })}
              </select>
              <select onChange={e => handlePeriodChange(e)}>
                  <option value ="all">all</option>
                  {Array.from(new Set(new_comparables.map(obj => obj.period))).map(period => {
                       return <option value={period}>{period}</option>
                  })}
              </select>
              <select onChange={e => handleValueChange(e)}>
                 {valid.map((obj) => {
                       return <option value={obj.id}>{obj.variable}</option>
                 })}
              </select>
              <select onChange={e => handleVariableChange(e)}>
                 {variables.map((obj) => {
                       return <option value={obj.id}>{obj.variable}</option>
                 })}
              </select>
           </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have items array that shown in table:

0- init:

```
A:const [originalItems, null] = useState([{...},{...},etc...]);
B:const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState([{...},{...},etc...]);
```

1- filters:

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([{name:'field1',value:'all'},etc...]);
```

2- handle changes:
assum you have some drop down:

```
    A: onChange={(txt)=>handleChange('field1',txt)}

    B:handleChange(name,val){
    setFilters([...filters,{name,value}]);
    let items = [...originalItems];
    for(let i=0;i<filters.length;i++){
       items = items.filter(x=>x[filters[i]] === val);//condition to pass
    }
       setFilteredItems([...items ]);
    }
```

in above code you can change condition to pass
3- use filtered items like this:

```
filteredItems.map(item=>(<div>
//what ever ui is?
</div>))
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure out how to perform the filter without changing the logic used. I realized I was performing the filtering wrongly. So instead of having this syntax:

```
comparable.module == moduleSelected.value !== 'all'
```

I decided to instead use an if else statement (ternary operators) to subdue that :
the code below checked if  `moduleSelected.value !== 'all'` and executes else an empty block is passed `{}` in this case, an equivalent of doing a `pass` in Python

```
moduleSelected.value !== 'all'?comparable.module == moduleSelected.value:{}
```

So overally :

```
let filteredComparables = [];
moduleSelected.value === 'all' || variableSelected.value === 'all'||
valueSelected.value ==='all' || periodSelected.value === 'all'?
    filteredComparables = new_comparables
    :filteredComparables = new_comparables.filter(comparable => (
        comparable.module == moduleSelected.value !== 'all'
        &&comparable.table == variableSelected.value !== 'all'
        &&comparable.is_valid == valueSelected.value !== 'all'
        &&comparable.period == periodSelected.value !== 'all'))
```

becomes :

```
let filteredComparables = [];
    filteredComparables = new_comparables.filter(comparable => (
        (moduleSelected.value !== 'all'?comparable.module == moduleSelected.value:{})
        &&(variableSelected.value !== 'all'?comparable.table == variableSelected.value:{})
        &&(valueSelected.value !== 'all'?comparable.is_valid == valueSelected.value:{})
        &&(periodSelected.value !== 'all'?comparable.period == periodSelected.value:{})))
```